# JSS interrogations

Tags: material-ui, jss

I am using CSS in JS (JSS) with material-ui, it works fine, but i don't get what it's supposed to offer (more than style injection) in terms of features/coding facilities. I feel like i am missing something so i have some specific questions.

With the style injection, i can adapt the style to the context, for instance:

```
const buttonStyle = {
  border: "2px solid black »,
  borderRadius: "5px",
  padding: "15px",
  font-family: "15px",
  font-size: "2em",
  backbroundColor: "red"
};

if (success) {
  buttonStyle.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

With JSS, it looks like i need to "pre-build" the whole button style in its different potential colors:

```
const style = {
  buttonSuccess: {
    border: "2px solid black »,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    padding: "15px",
    font-family: "15px",
    font-size: "2em",
    backbroundColor: « green »
  }, 
  buttonError: {
    border: "2px solid black",
    borderRadius: "5px",
    padding: "15px",
    font-family: "15px",
    font-size: "2em",
    backbroundColor: "red"
  }
};
```

Is there any way to avoid to re-write the whole style when only one parameter is dynamic?

And another point, with JSS, it looks like we need to inject one class for each html element we need to style.

So if i have a table with 200 cells, am i supposed to add 200 classes into my DOM (when i could declare it only one time with a `td` selector in pure CSS)?

Is there a way to work with inherit style between parent and children components? 
Because there is a dirty pattern i have written several time to merge a style i inject from the parent and the style the children compile by itself:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
});

const childComponent = (props) => (
  <div classeName={`${props.parentClass} ${props.classes}`} /> // See parentClass here
);

export default withStyles(styles)(childComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to avoid to re-write the whole style when only one parameter is dynamic?

Yes, see function values. http://cssinjs.org/json-api?v=v9.8.1#function-values

> So if i have a table with 200 cells, am i supposed to add 200 classes into my DOM (when i could declare it only one time with a td selector in pure CSS)?

You can use '& td' selector, see jss-nested plugin, it is already built in.

http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested?v=v6.0.1

> Is there a way to work with inherit style between parent and children components?

JSS doesn't modify inheritance model of CSS. I think you are trying to override a property that is defined by the core. Check out customization documentation https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: Ok i see functions value are not really ready to use with material-ui since the props are not injected to the callback that return the style yet, but there are issues on that. For the last point, it's more about a merge between style from the parent (props) and the children. For instance, an <Icon /> component, only the parent can say what size the icon should be (fontSize), so what is the proper way for the parent to inject the fontSize?